# Where is the decimal coming from in this calculation?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that calcuates a BOL number and only take the first 10 digits.

Here's the code.

```
Public Function GENERATEBOLNUMBER(iYearSuffix As Integer, _
                              sFromZipcode As String, _
                              sToZipCode As String, _
                              iWeight As Integer, _
                              iShowID As Integer) As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    GENERATEBOLNUMBER = VBA.Left(7 & _
    WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(VBA.Right(sFromZipcode, 5) _
    * VBA.Right(sToZipCode, 5) * iWeight * (iShowID + 1234), 0), 10)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

And here are the values I'm passing it. 7 for the iYearSuffix, 78224 for sFromZipcode and 78224 for sToZipCode, 410 as the iWeight, and 1 as the iShowID. All of this calculates to 3098352701017600, so the final string should be 7309835270, which is the 7 included as the first digit and the following 9 digits.

Where is the decimal coming from? The answer I'm getting is: 73.0983527.

Comment: Did you verify the formatting on each cell being pulled into this code?  All I can think is that you're pulling values in that are considered less than 1, at 7 orders less than intended.

Comment: When numbers get too big in Excel, it switches to scientific notation so it's probably 3.0983527E+10 or something like that

Comment: Anyway to convert it from scientific? If I use the same formulas as an Excel formula, it calculates it correct, until until I use my custom function will it do it wrong.

Comment: Hi, @JoelSpolsky, I am a good reader of JoS, I found a broken link there. In your reading list, select "Fog Creek Software" and in the very first paragraph of the details, there's a link, [Fog Creek Software](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/fogcreek.com) which is broken. I couldn't find a way to tell you about this thus commenting here. I will delete this comment tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing string handling, numeric manipulation, implicit casts between strings and numbers, VBA, WorksheetFunction, and gigantic numbers.  What could possibly go wrong?

If you're going to write a UDF in VBA, write it in VBA.  The only data type large enough to store your result is going to be a `Decimal`, so you'll have to declare it as a `Variant` and explicitly cast the calculation to force it to coerce:

```
Public Function GENERATEBOLNUMBER(yearSuffix As Integer, fromZip As String, _
                                  toZip As String, weight As Integer, _
                                  showId As Integer) As String
    Dim result As Variant
    'Calculate intermediary result.
    result = CDec(Right$(fromZip, 5)) * CDec(Right$(toZip, 5)) * weight * (showId + 1234)
    'Shift the decimal place 7 places to the left:
    result = result / 10 ^ 7
    'Skip the RoundUp call - it wasn't doing anything because your result was an integer.
    'Strip the non-integer portion:
    result = Fix(result)
    'Cast to a string an concatenate the "7" onto the start:
    GENERATEBOLNUMBER = "7" & CStr(result)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you! Also, what does the dollar sign mean in the function call? `Right$`? I've tried Googling it, but only results about using the dollar sign in formula for cell references show up.

Comment: @JozemiteApps - It's a type hint for the function. A bunch of the string handling functions have a version that returns `String` and a version that return a `Variant`.  The `$` specifies the `String` returning one. There's some [additional info in Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/877/declaring-variables/2960/type-hints).